# How do I get iFramed images to show up in RSS?

Tags: html, rss, iframe

I switched to Skydrive for my image hosting recently, and after getting the page formatting the way it needed to be, I ran into an issue with my RSS feed. In particular, when I used `img src=` the image would show up in the feed. However, the images in iFrames do not.

The iFrames are formatted perfectly for my margins and all I need to do is copy and paste an embed code. With the `img`, I will need to add all of the dimension code. Obviously I would like to continue using iFrames since they fit well and need little work, `img src` is a do-able but more involved solution (read: I don't want to have to tinker around in HTML if possible).

Most of all I just want all the images on my page to show up in my reader: what are my options?

Comment: here's a prior question for some more background on my Skydrive probs http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/4539/1920

Comment: You don't need to add "dimension code"... `<img src="image.jpg">` on its own is fine. The browser will show the image at its correct size.

Comment: right, but the size on skydrive is 1600px wide, though some post around 600px wide: and my page's margin is 660px, so when I want to drop to images side by side I need to define dimensions.

Comment: So resize your images and use proper thumbnails. Don't make users download a 1600px image when they're only going to see it as 600px wide. Proper thumbnails save bandwidth and look better because they're resampled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `iframe`s? `iframe`s and `frame`s should be avoided as much as possible, especially for content, as they present problems for screen readers, search engines, text-based browsers, and a lot of other HTML applications.

RSS support for HTML has always been spotty at best. Different readers have different levels of support. `iframe`s, which already have few legitimate uses on a webpage, have no legitimate uses at all in a newsfeed. In fact, it presents an XSS problem for web-based readers.

Comment: Like I said in the post, I am using iFrames (knowingly despite SEO concerns) for the sake of expedience since Skydrive provides an iFrame embed code on their image pages. My post here is to find out if there is a middle ground, in terms of ease, between crappy iFrames and blocks and blocks of `img src`

Comment: What do you mean by middle ground? You either use iframes or you don't. And how is using "blocks and blocks" of `iframe src` any better than using `img` tags?